# Is there a way to integrate PayOne Api and JS SDK into Expo React Native App?

Tags: react-native, expo, payment-gateway, payment-processing, payone

I have read the documentation of PayOne but there doesn't seem to be any example on this topic in discussion. It would be really helpful if any of you could be of some help.

Some code examples or any for that matter would be great.

Comment: What kind of app are you trying to build ?

Comment: I am building a marketplace app for my virtual restaurants like doordash or takeaway, the problem is that I know how to integrate other types of payment processing api but the bank I have an account with only allows integration of PayOne to process payments.